# Receive JSON data from a webservice using REST API

Tags: java, json, rest

I need to receive JSON data from this Api http://countryapi.gear.host/v1/Country/getCountries using REST API. I need to receive `NativeName` and `Region` for the specific country.

My main problem is how to send request for the specific country (for example I print `Name` Australia) and get the response for `NativeName` and `Region` - Australia, Oceania (it should be String).

I have such classes:

```
  public class Client {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {

HttpClient clientGetEntity = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://countryapi.gear.host/v1/Country/getCountries?pName=Australia");
request.addHeader("accept", "application/json");
HttpResponse responseGetEntity = clientGetEntity.execute(request);
//String json =EntityUtils.toString((HttpEntity) responseGetEntity);
System.out.println("Request : " + request.toString());
System.out.println("Response : " + responseGetEntity.toString());
}
```

}

Comment: What are the API parameters? You're asking us to provide information about a service which many of us have no idea about. Start by reading the services API documentation

Comment: Okay, stop, go read [How to use/Request Parameters](https://github.com/fabian7593/CountryAPI#request-parameters), it also has examples

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the answer is readily available via the [API Documentation](https://github.com/fabian7593/CountryAPI#request-parameters), including examples

Comment: there are no examples in java

Comment: No, but you have the query requirements which you can test

Comment: So, I used `java.net.URL` and posted `http://countryapi.gear.host/v1/Country/getCountries?pName=Australia`  which returned a `JSON` response including `NativeName` and `Region` elements. I fail to see what you're trying to ask. Are you asking about the parameters you need?  Are you asking about how to parse the JSON response? Are you asking about something else which we seem to be missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDITS**

As regards getting the specific country's name, you need to make a get request with the country name such as:

`http://countryapi.gear.host/v1/Country/getCountries?pName=Australia`

The response from this request:

`{
    "IsSuccess": true,
    "UserMessage": null,
    "TechnicalMessage": null,
    "TotalCount": 1,
    "Response": [
        {
            "Name": "Australia",
            "Alpha2Code": "AU",
            "Alpha3Code": "AUS",
            "NativeName": "Australia",
            "Region": "Oceania",
            "SubRegion": "Australia and New Zealand",
            "Latitude": "-27",
            "Longitude": "133",
            "Area": 7692024,
            "NumericCode": 36,
            "NativeLanguage": "eng",
            "CurrencyCode": "AUD",
            "CurrencyName": "Australian dollar",
            "CurrencySymbol": "$",
            "Flag": "https://api.backendless.com/2F26DFBF-433C-51CC-FF56-830CEA93BF00/473FB5A9-D20E-8D3E-FF01-E93D9D780A00/files/CountryFlags/aus.svg",
            "FlagPng": "https://api.backendless.com/2F26DFBF-433C-51CC-FF56-830CEA93BF00/473FB5A9-D20E-8D3E-FF01-E93D9D780A00/files/CountryFlagsPng/aus.png"
        }
    ]
}`

You can access NativeName and region by:

`data.Response[0].NativeName` and `data.Response[0].Region` respectively.

Since the data returned from the API is always a JSON string, dont forget to parse the string before use.

### ----------------------------------------

I am not a java developer but I have dealt with a lot of JSON data, Also C# and TypeScript projects. 
First, you should take a look at this line:
`request.addHeader("accept", "application/fson");`

Am afraid this is not a valid JSON request header and if we where to start debugging your code, it would be difficult to pinpoint where the problem lies if the basis of the whole request is faulty. Please correct to:
`request.addHeader("accept", "application/json");` and try again, if you have the same result, we can continue debugging from there.

Comment: of course it must be `json`, my mistake, but anyway it doesn't work

Comment: do you have link to the API documentation?

Comment: edited answer with observations for getting specific country details. Apologies I wouldn't  be able to show you the specific code to do this in java, but if you want, I can write a typeScript implementation you can follow.